# Error when trying to open Ganache on Ubuntu: archive type not supported

Tags: ganache, ubuntu

After downloading a fresh copy of the latest [Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases/) and double click to run it, the following error is shown:

> archive type not supported

Versions
Ubuntu: 16 and 17

All Ganache versions: for example 1.2.3 and 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Ganache. It is related to Linux Ubuntu. The file mode has to be changed to be executable as follow:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ chmod a+x ganache-1.1.0-x86_64.AppImage
$ ./ganache-1.1.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

reference: https://github.com/cogeorg/teaching/wiki/Installing-Ganache

---

This could be also done by Right Click then press Properties then at Permissions tab, enable the option `Allow executing file as program`:

[image: Allow executing file as program]